# How to make a value last for multiple frames?

Tags: animation, animation-nodes

I have a simple `switch` based on a `sound spectrum`.
When the value hits above `0.15` the condition returns `true` which i've set to output `1`:

[image]

However I would like that whenever the condition is `true` it doesn't just return `1` for that frame but **for the following 3 frames**.

I've tried using `animate float` node but I couldn't figure out how to use that node to achieve this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can do this with this node setup:

[image]

the expressions are just writing and reading the framestart value, which is that frame, when the condition (>= .6) was last time true.

The list viewer shows random values from 0 to 1.

The viewer on top of the list viewer shows the current random value.

The two other viewers show frame and the result you want.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the answer, i've tried reproducing it but I am always getting ``false`` : https://imgur.com/a/GJM3mgK

Comment: Pls provide your blend file so I can check it out

Comment: Sure here it is, i've kept it as a Minimum Reproducible Example : https://mega.nz/file/vNkziZBD#d-mwbxIGG-iQADcrhYxpiAXV6-BIvFDBHgZP8h6vctM

Comment: no wonder, that's because your compare here always returns false : [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/RwIAI.png

Comment: by the way: you should do file->external data-> pack resources before uploading your file to make sure we are looking at exactly the same file. maybe the error i found because you didn't add the sound file

Comment: Yes sorry it's because I didn't include the audio file, I should have mentioned that, I will upload it the way you suggested

Comment: The file which should also contain the audio : https://mega.nz/file/DBUklJLa#ZioSej-XLXW_LHw5uXDipdMlXYIR_NsQFz6PaOlrQqA

Comment: it took me a while - you have chosen the wrong input type. Here: [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/QTqs8.png please delete frame start as input there, press + again and choose integer, then rename to framestart and plug the frame back in. Same on the other expression with framestart. if you made it right, the input will turn purple: [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/DUfvb.png

Comment: and of course, if you start your testing with frame 400, you have to ask for frame == 400 instead of frame == 1

Comment: That works, thank you!

Comment: You are welcome!